# Target variable error when building a decision tree classifier in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

```
X = balance_data.values[:, 1:5]
Y = balance_data.values[:,0]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)

clf_entropy = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy", random_state = 100,
 max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)
clf_entropy.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I try to run the above code to fit data and train the model it gives me the following error. I am using google colab for python
can anyone please help me with this?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-3523056235b2> in <module>()
      1 clf_entropy= DecisionTreeClassifier()
----> 2 clf_entropy.fit(X_train, y_train)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    167     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    168                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 169         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a sample of data in your dataframe `balance_data` so we can help.

Comment: Also  the full error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DecisionTreeClassifier` will check the type of target variable you have, so if each entry is a tuple or list, it will issue that warning, for example, this is how it should go:

```
balance_data = pd.concat([
pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['A','B'],100)),
pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,5)))
],axis=1)

X = balance_data.values[:, 1:5]
Y = balance_data.values[:,0]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)

clf_entropy = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy", random_state = 100,
 max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)
clf_entropy.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now if your target variable is a list or list:

```
balance_data.iloc[:,0] = [[np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],1)] for i in range(100)]
X = balance_data.values[:, 1:5]
Y = balance_data.values[:,0]

Y[0]
Out[36]: [array(['C'], dtype='<U1')]
```

Then it will throw the same warning like you saw:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)

clf_entropy = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy", random_state = 100,
 max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)
clf_entropy.fit(X_train, y_train)

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

What you should do is check what is in balance_data.values[:,0], and make sure there's no embedded list or tuple.